# iPad zoom to fit doesn't work on webpage with minimal content

Tags: html, css, ipad, viewport

Consider the following rudimentary html code block:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>iPad test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body
        {
            margin:0;
        }
        #content
        {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 980px;
            border:1px solid #c4c4c4;
            background-color:#f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    A small amount of content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When viewed on an iPad, the main content area of 980px will not be auto zoomed to fit the iPad screen. However, if you replace `A small amount of content` with a large amount of content, ie... enough to cause vertical scrolling, the page is auto zoomed on the iPad.

Does anyone know why this is? I have been searching high and low and can't seem to find a way to force the auto zooming to occur when there is minimal content on the page.

Changing the viewport content to `width=980` fixes the issue of course, however I am creating a responsive website, therefore the viewport needs to be `device-width`.

I am using a media query to alter the CSS for the content area on smart phones (to 100% width), and I was hoping to use the standard desktop version of the website for iPads.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Note: I am testing on an iPad with retina display, I'm not sure what happens on older models.

Comment: searching high and low and i found this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a break from this, I came back with a different angle - if setting the viewport width to a specific value fixes my issue for the iPad, why not do just that.

So the solution for me was to default the viewport width to device-width to handle smart phone devices, then detect for iPads and adjust the viewport width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=980');
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for your suggestions [insertusernamehere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1456376/insertusernamehere)

Comment: Thanks, this just saved my bacon after spending all evening trying to come up with a workaround in css. Its absolutely ridiculous that we have to do this for the iPhone. iPad was fine with just some minor tweaking but the iPhone has serious issues with content that is very short on a page. Nothing I tried before this made any difference to the fact that the viewport simply would not show the full width of the content.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The whole content will fit afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, in fact it makes it worse; the page with a large amount of text is not scaled either which makes complete sense as an initial scale of 1 would force the content to be the defined width of 980px, however the viewport is 768px.

Comment: Hm, I tested it on an iPad 3 running iOs 5.1.1 - it worked perfectly with the short text you posted and with a large amount of text in landscape mode. If you want it to fit portrait mode, that doesn't work. Is a width of 100% in portrait mode, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah it seems to be okay in landscape (even without initial-scale-1.0), but I need it to be consistent in portrait as well. I just want the site to zoom to fit to 100% of the iPad width in landscape & portrait, like it does when there is a large amount of content.

Comment: For me it only worked with initial scale set on an iPad 3 in landscape mode. Still looking for a solution for portrait mode.

Comment: @insertusernamehere thanks! That was just what I was looking for in my project!