# CSS iPad View Layout

Tags: css, ipad, width, viewport

Got sample set up here: http://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/myxDc and full page sample at: http://codepen.io/rctneil/full/myxDc

On that sample, I have a header with a .container within it, header is full width and .container is fixed to a particular width.

If you set the width to be 980 pixels or less then the page renders nicely on an iPad, if you set that width to be greater than 980 pixels then you start getting erroneous space on the right hand side.

I thought the default layout mode on iPad was that if an element is wider than the visual viewport, the visual viewport would zoom out until everything fitted and then allow the user to manually zoom into parts of the page. This is how it has worked in the past for me, I am sure.

Anyone know why the site is not auto zooming out to fit correctly?

Comment: I think the second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306973/ipad-zoom-to-fit-doesnt-work-on-webpage-with-minimal-content will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height of the page large enough to require vertical scrolling, it will automatically shrink down the width. For example, set the width and height to 2000px on .container, and it shrinks the page appropriately. This probably isn't a viable solution in this circumstance, but it is a interesting observation of iPad viewport behavior.

I would recommend using iOS meta viewport tags. http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: That is really weird. I wonder why it doesn't zoom out when the vertical height is not very tall - That's the behaviour I would ahve expected and actually do wish.

I want to keep width=device-width but want it to behave like that. If I set a specific width and have to do browser sniffing it just feels messy and wrong.